# Value of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, string, arrays, json

When I return string from another activity and try to convert it to JSONArray, the program show me this:

```
08-22 14:51:35.313: E/YourCartActivity(1134): Error parsing data 
org.json.JSONException:
Value {"yourCart_totalPrice":"5500.00","yourCart_productName":"AAA",
"yourCart_productImg":"http:\/\/10.0.2.2\/appserv\/products\/aaa02.jpg",
"yourCart_productID":"0000002",
"yourCart_productAmount":"2",
"yourCart_shopID":"001"} 
of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

does anybody know how to solve this problem?

This my code:

```
String json = yourCartConnect.getYourCartDetails();

        try {
            JSONArray jResult = new JSONArray(json);


            for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++){
                JSONObject f = jResult.getJSONObject(i);
                YourCartEntry resultRow = new YourCartEntry();

                resultRow.setYourCart_shopID(f.getString("yourCart_shopID"));
                resultRow.setYourCart_totalPrice(f.getString("yourCart_totalPrice"));
                resultRow.setYourCart_productName(f.getString("yourCart_productName"));     
                resultRow.setYourCart_productID(f.getString("yourCart_productID"));
                resultRow.setYourCart_productImg(f.getString("yourCart_productImg"));
                resultRow.setYourCart_productAmount(f.getString("yourCart_productAmount"));

                yourCartEntries.add(resultRow);
            }

        setList(yourCartEntries);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("YourCartActivity", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            errorConnectToServer();
        }
```

Comment: your json is a json object, not a json array ...

Comment: Are you using PHP to build the JSON response string?

Comment: Post full code  , please!

Comment: you are parsing Jsonobject in JsonArray . Data inside [] is JsonArray and inside {} with key value pair is JSONObject

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code:

```
String json = yourCartConnect.getYourCartDetails();



         try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json)
                JSONArray jResult = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Your array key");

                for(int i=0;i<jResult.length();i++){
                    JSONObject f = jResult.getJSONObject(i);
                   // write your remaining code here
                }

            setList(yourCartEntries);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("YourCartActivity", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                errorConnectToServer();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
try {
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray("your JSON result........");
    JSONObject json_data = null;
    StringBuilder print = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
        json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        System.out.println("json_data : " + json_data);
        System.out.println("\n");
        print.append(json_data.getString("yourCart_shopID") + ", " + 
            json_data.getString("yourCart_totalPrice") + ", " + 
            json_data.getString("yourCart_productName") + ", " + 
            json_data.getString("yourCart_productID") + ", " + 
            json_data.getString("yourCart_productImg") + ", " + 
            json_data.getString("yourCart_productAmount") + "\n");
        yourCartEntries.add(print.toString());
    }
    setList(yourCartEntries);
} catch (JSONException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have JSONObject String, not a JSONArray,

[JSONArray here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html)

EG:

```
[{"yourCart_totalPrice":"5500.00","yourCart_productName":"AAA","yourCart_productImg":"http:\/\/10.0.2.2\/appserv\/products\/aaa02.jpg","yourCart_productID":"0000002","yourCart_productAmount":"2","yourCart_shopID":"001"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
String json = yourCartConnect.getYourCartDetails();

        try {
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(json)){
              JSONObject f=new JSONObject(json);
              YourCartEntry resultRow = new YourCartEntry();    
              resultRow.setYourCart_shopID(f.getString("yourCart_shopID"));
              resultRow.setYourCart_totalPrice(f.getString("yourCart_totalPrice"));
              resultRow.setYourCart_productName(f.getString("yourCart_productName"));     
              resultRow.setYourCart_productID(f.getString("yourCart_productID"));
              resultRow.setYourCart_productImg(f.getString("yourCart_productImg"));
              resultRow.setYourCart_productAmount(f.getString("yourCart_productAmount"));
              setList(resultRow);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("YourCartActivity", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            errorConnectToServer();
        }
```